# Realized GARCH - specify “realizedVol” in the model fit

Tags: r, time-series, volatility

I want to estimate Realized GARCH (1,1) model. In my dataset I have the following time series:

```
ret <- replicate(1, rnorm(100))
RV <- replicate(1, rnorm(100))
date <- c(1:100)
```

I do the following:

```
install.packages("rugarch")
library(rugarch)
attspec <- ugarchspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0, 0), include.mean = FALSE), variance.model = list(model = 'realGARCH', garchOrder = c(1, 1)))
fit <- ugarchfit(spec=attspec, data=ret, solver = 'hybrid', realizedVol = RV[, 1])
```

After the last line I get an error: *realizedVol must be an xts object*

I tried to convert my RV matrix into xts object using the examples given in the description of the xts package:

```
require(xts)
rownames(RV) <- date
matrix_xts <- as.xts(RV,dateFormat='Date')
```

or

```
df_xts <- as.xts(as.data.frame(RV))
```

In both cases the error is *character string is not in a standard unambiguous format*

So, what should I do in order to make a suitable format of xts objest for the realizedVol specification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have both `ret` and `RV` as `xts` objects, they can be initialized in the following way:

```
times<-Sys.time()+date
ret_xts<-xts(ret,order.by = times)
RV_xts <- xts(RV,order.by = times)
```

and then you can successfully call:

```
fit <- ugarchfit(spec=attspec, data=ret_xts, solver = 'hybrid', realizedVol = RV_xts)
```

Comment: What do these error messages mean: 

Warning messages: 
1: In log(realized[1:length(data)]) : NaNs produced 
2: In .makefitmodel(garchmodel = "realGARCH", f = .realgarchLLH, T = T, : rugarch-->warning: failed to invert hessian

Comment: It is diagnostic related to the fit